# Cordova navigator.notification.prompt max length or prevent from expanding

Tags: cordova, modal-dialog, prompt

I have a call for the `navigator.notification.prompt` to be able to enter some text. However, I have found that if I constantly just hit `Enter`, eventually the buttons disappear of the screen because of the size of the modal.

Is there any way to set a max length for these prompt modals or prevent it from going off screen?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No there isn't, as you can see from the [plugin's documentation page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs).

You could instead implement your own dialogs with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and customize them to your needs, but of course this requires much more customization and programming.